# Error connecting: <class 'thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException'>

Tags: thrift, cloudera, impala

I have installed Cloudera Impala v0.4 via Cloudera Manager 4.1.3

my cluster comprises of only to slave machines

```
slave1 --> Impala Daemon, State Store daemon
slave2 --> Impala Daemon
```

So, I am able to run impala shell on these machines-

```
>impala-shell
```

The problem is, when i run the command (in slave1/slave2)

```
[Not connected] > connect impalad-host:21000
```

I get the following error:

```
Error connecting: class 'thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException'
Could not connect to impalad-shell:21000
```

Here impalad-host is the host name by default running on port no `21000`.

How do I configure the host name and the port no?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue!

Comment: Ok so I solved this issue. Hive was using Derby as metastore and Impala cannot work with derby. It can only work with MySql or Postgresql. Can you please check hive-site.xml to see if you can find mysql mentioned somewhere? This xml will be present somewhere in /usr/lib/hive/conf..on some path on these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a three year old question, I am still going to add my two cents for anyone who lands up on this page looking for a solution-

Look here for an answer [Modifying Impala Startup Options](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/1-x/1-2-4/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_config_options.html)

> **Configuring Impala Startup Options through the Command Line**
>
> When you run Impala in a non-Cloudera Manager environment, the Impala server,
> statestore, and catalog services start up using values provided in a
> defaults file, /etc/default/impala.
>
> This file includes information about many resources used by Impala.
> Most of the defaults included in this file should be effective in most
> cases. For example, typically you would not change the definition of
> the CLASSPATH variable, but you would always set the address used by
> the statestore server. Some of the content you might modify include:
>
> **IMPALA_STATE_STORE_HOST=127.0.0.1**
>
> **IMPALA_STATE_STORE_PORT=24000**
>
> IMPALA_BACKEND_PORT=22000
>
> IMPALA_LOG_DIR=/var/log/impala